# perl if( -e "windows with space path){}

Tags: windows, perl, path, executable, space

I'm on **Windows** :-/ and in my script i've:

```
$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt
```

That give me:

```
C:\Program\ Files\EMC\PowerPath\powermt
```

if I do a `if(-e $ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt)` it doesn't work.

I have try to change my path with some substitution \ /

I have also try to add more double quote but nothing seems to work :-(

Exemple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

if($^O =~ m/^MSWin32$/){
    my $tmp = File::Spec->catdir($ENV{'Powmig Path'}, "powermt");
    if(-e "\"$tmp\""){
        print "powermt found\n";
    }else{
        print "No multipathing found \"$tmp\"\n";
    }
    $tmp =~ s/\\/\//g;
    if(-e "\"$tmp\""){
        print "powermt found\n";
    }else{
        print "No multipathing found \"$tmp\"\n";
    }
}else{
    print "Error: Unknow OS\n";
}
exit;
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\sgargasson\Desktop>perl test.pl
No multipathing found "C:\Program Files\EMC\PowerPath\powermt"
No multipathing found "C:/Program Files/EMC/PowerPath/powermt"
```

After some try with different files, the problem comming from the space...

Can somebody help me?

Thx in Adv

Comment: Perhaps you should include the actual *code* that you have used. I have no problem doing file tests `-e` on paths with space in them in windows. It is more than likely that your problem is simply that you have done something wrong with your code.

Comment: And also, never, ever, ever include approximate code. Always, always include code you have used yourself, that describes your exact problem.

Comment: re: Edit: You still have not done the `-e` file test on the string before you changed it. Two parts: 1) you are using the `-x` file test. 2) you are doing the file test after changing the string.

Comment: I've try directly then with lot of changes with the -e and -x tests. No difference :-(

Answer (score 5):

You do realize that you cannot just type a string into the source code, right? You need to quote it:

```
print "$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt";
...
if (-e "$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt")
```

This will interpolate the variable, in this case a hash value from the hash `%ENV`, and concatenate it with the string `powermt`.

And if you do try to concatenate a string to a variable, you first need to quote it, and then use an [operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) to attach it to the variable:

```
my $string = $ENV{'Powmig Path'} . "powermt";
#                                ^--- concatenation operator
```

If you are trying to build paths, though, you might use a module suitable for that task, such as [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSpec):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my $path = File::Spec->catdir($ENV{'Powmig Path'}, "powermt");
```

Comment: I've try with concat and File::Spec, not better :-(

Comment: Do this. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $path; system("dir", $path);` see if you have any hidden whitespace characters wrong, and see if your shell can find the file with dir.

Comment: I do my $path=$ENV{'Powmig Path'}; OUTPUT: $VAR1 = "C:\\Program Files\\EMC\\PowerPath\\"; After it display the dir

Comment: So your shell did not find that directory. And if you type directly in your shell `dir "%Powmig Path%"`?

Comment: Eh... the stuff you pasted before your edit said "File not found".

Comment: It was because $path was "C:\Program Files\EMC\PowerPath\powermt" :-)

Comment: I need a reputation of twenty to talk to you :-) But I'm on

Comment: I show you but I can't answer... Can you give me a parts of your incredible reputation??? :-p

Comment: @SylvainGargasson No, unfortunately I can't, you only gain rep by getting your contributions upvoted. So what did you mean by "it was because $path was ..."? What is "it"?

Comment: How can I increase my reputation quickly? I don't want to answer some craps for having reputation :-)

Comment: @SylvainGargasson You can chat now, Perl chat came to your rescue.

Comment: my path was the powermt executable file

Comment: I have now 28 of reputation BUT the chat say "You need 20 to speak" :-)

Comment: I have not waiting you for that but not better :-) I have close and reload firefox also...

Comment: Ok, perhaps it just needs some time to update. What do you mean, that `powermt` is the executable file? Shouldn't that be `powermt.EXE` in that case?

Comment: Ho man, I'm to much an asshole... I'm to mutch in Linux :-p I will try it

Comment: Hehe, you would be surprised how often very small things are the cause of long hours of debugging. That's why you always have to include all the small details when asking others. :) You're welcome, and good luck.

Comment: Thx a lot for your indulgence :-)

Comment: @SylvainGargasson That's what I am here for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a LOT to TLP

I'm so a stupid linux user!!!!

PROBLEM:

```
my $tmp="$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt";
```

SOLVE:

```
my $tmp="$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt.exe";
```

CORRECT CODE IS:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if($^O =~ m/^MSWin32$/){
    if(-e "$ENV{'Powmig Path'}powermt.exe"){
        print "powermt found\n";
    }else{
        print "No multipathing found\n";
    }
}else{
    print "Error: Unknow OS\n";
}
exit;
```

I'm so stupid, I need to uncheck "Hide know extension" So many hours in this things...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem:

```
if(-e "\"$tmp\""){
```

You've got an extra set of quotes. The filename isn't `"C:\Program Files\whatever"`, it's `C:\Program Files\whatever`. You only want those extra quotes if the filename is being interpreted by the Command Prompt, or something like that, and that's not the case here.

Try this instead, where I've removed the extraneous quotes (`"\"$tmp\""` becomes `"$tmp"`, which is exactly the same as `$tmp`):

```
if ( -e $tmp ) {
```