# What does '! -e "/etc/httpd"' in Perl in 'if' Condition

Tags: linux, perl

Please explain what following code snippet could do in Perl script,

```
if (! -e '/etc/httpd') {
   print "Something";
}
```

I can't find exact scenario or condition that makes this condition 'true'. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118633/perl-if-e-windows-with-space-path) also not explain much regarding this.

Exactly, what `-e` switch does in this condition?

Comment: See [filetests ("-X")](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). The `-e` checks for existence of a file (as "entry", not only a plain file).  So this tests whether `/etc/httpd` does not exist, since `!` negates.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. That works. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: @zdim make that an answer?

Comment: @ysth Alright, if you think it should be done.  I never know with things that cleanly fit in a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-e filename` is one of [filetests ("-X")](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), which checks for existence of a "file" (an entry, not only a plain file).

So the condition tests whether `/etc/httpd` does not exist, since the unary [operator `!`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators) does logical negation of what is on its right-hand side using Perl's rules for truth and falsehood.